# monitor for file then copy to another directory

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, file-copying

I'm relatively new to unix scripting, so apologies for the newbie question.

I need to create a script which will permanently run in the background, and monitor for a file to arrive in an FTP landing directory, then copy it to a different directory, and lastly remove the file from the original directory.

The script is running on a Ubuntu box.

The landing directory is /home/vpntest

The file needs to be copied as /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

So far, I've got this

```
#/home/vpntest/FTP_file_copy.sh
if [ -f vvpn_azure.txt ]; then
cp vvpn_azure.txt /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
rm vvpn_azure.txt
fi
```

I can run this as root, and it works, but only as a one off (I need it to run permanently in the background, and trigger each time a new file is received in the landing zone.)

If I don't run as root, I get issues with permissions (even if I run it from within the directory /home/vpntest.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any estimate as to approximately how often a new vvpn_azure.txt wil land in /home/vpntest ?

Comment: You can try to use the inotify-tools to get informed, when a new file arrives from the ftp in you directory you watch and then take an action e.g. call a script. It's less resource consuming than polling the directory for new content.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** crontab correction and extra info

One way to have a check and move process in background with root permissions, is the "polling" approach done via root user's crontab, with your script.

Steps:

1. Revise your /home/vpntest/FTP_file_copy.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

new_file=/home/vpntest/vvpn_azure.txt

if [ -f "$new_file" ]; then
    mv $new_file /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
fi
```

2. Log out. Log in as root user.
3. Add a cron task to run the script:

   crontab -e

If this is a new machine, and your first time running crontab, you may get a prompt first to choose an editor for crontab, just choose and continue into the editor.

The format is  `m h dom mon dow command`, so if checking every 5 minutes is sufficiently frequent, do:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/vpntest/FTP_file_copy.sh
```

4. Save and close to apply.

It will now automatically run the script every `5` minutes in the background, helping you to move the file if found.

### Explanation

Root user, because you mentioned it only worked for you as root.

So we set this in the root user's crontab to have sufficient permissions.

`man 5 crontab` informs us:

> Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say
>   'every two hours', just use '*/2'.

Thus we write `*/5` in the first column, which is the minutes column,
to set for "every 5 minutes".

FTP_file_copy.sh:

- uses absolute paths, can run from anywhere
- re-arranged so one variable `new_file` can be re-used
- good practice to enclose any values being checked within your `[` `]` test
- uses `mv` to write over the destination while removing itself from the source directory

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, and detailed explanation. Thats really helpful. I'll check this out later.